# Find Lebesgue Integral: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^2f_n(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Consider a sequence of functions $f_n:[0,2]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x^n)}{x^n}$ for all other $x$.  Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^2f_n(x)dx$.

My attempt:
$\sup_{x\in(0,2]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x\in(0,2]}|\frac{\sin(x^n)}{x^n}-0|$, thus, we have uniform convergence.  So, since the interval we are integrating over is finite and $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly, then by the Dominated Convergence Theorem, we may pass the limit into the integral.  So, we then have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^2f_n(x)dx=\int_0^2\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)dx=\int_0^20dx=0$.

I was wondering if I did this correctly, or if I made a mistake somewhere.  In particular, are there any missing small details?  I would really appreciate any insight!  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is not correct and even the value of the limit is wrong. It is not true that $f_n(x) \to 0$ uniformly on $(0,2]$. In fact $f_n(x) \to 1$ for $0<x<1$ since $x^{n} \to 0$ and $\frac {\sin x} x \to 1$ as $ x \to 0$. For $x>1$ the limit is $0$ and you can apply DCT to show that $\int_1^{2} f_n(x)dx \to 0$. Now $\int_0^{1} f_n(x) dx \to 1$ by DCT since $|\sin t| \leq t$ for all $t \geq 0$. So the right answer is $1$.

Comment: Thank you!  One more thing:  the same dominating function can be used for both integrals, correct?  Also, would the dominating function be $g(x)=x$ or $g(x)=x^n$?  I'm definitely weak in finding those integrable dominating functions.  Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @User7238 The dominating function is $g(x)=1 in both cases.

Comment: Ah, okay.... so just so I am thinking of this correctly:
If we would have uniform convergence (which was a big mistake on my part), then we wouldn't have needed to split the integral.  But, since we needed to split the integral, we can use DCT on both pieces...
For $0<x<1$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin x^n}{x^n}=1$, and we can evaluate the integral this way because the integrand is dominated by $g(x)=1$.
For $1\leq x\leq 2$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin x^n}{x^n}=0$, and we can do this, again, because the integrand is dominated by $g(x)=1$.

Comment: @User7238 Exactly, Your argument is now perfect.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much!  One FINAL thing: 
The pointwise convergence almost everywhere..... for this problem, we would need to check that to use DCT, but that happens everywhere outside of $x=0$, by hypothesis, so we'd be good.  But, in general, this should be checked, right?  I suppose I'm just seeing it as one other potential issue in these problems.

Comment: @User7238 Right, $x=0$ can be ignored because Lebesgue measure of $\{0\}$ is $0$. We only need convergence almost everywhere to apply DCT.

Answer (score 0):

For all $n$ you can calculate that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x^n)}{x^n} = \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\sin(y)}{y} = 1$. You will want to try to prove that $|f_n|\leq 2$ and use that $g(x)= 2$ dominates the sequence so that you can use the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Are you taking  limit as $x \to 0$ or $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Fixed n and letting $x\to 0$